# Undergraduate and Job Reference Letter for PhD Program?

Tags: phd, masters, funding, recommendation-letter

So I did my masters in the UK, but I didn't build any relationships with my professors (I wasn't thinking I would be wanting to do a PhD later on). I only saw my thesis tutor once during my whole dissertation. Now I want to apply to a PhD scholarship, and they ask for reference letters. I am currently employed in my home country and I can get reference letters from my job and from my undergraduate program that as well, I completed in my home country.

I think my chances of being granted with a scholarship decreases because I will not be submitting a reference letter from my Master's degree...

What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 2):

The absence of a reference from your latest academic qualification will raise questions. I think it would be better to get a less than glowing letter than have nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Will there be bad things written in a recommendation letter for your masters? Or is the worst thing which could happen is that your tutor would write that they didn't see you much due to X (where X is not your fault), and thus provide a cautious assessment?

If if is the latter, I agree with Spark's answer that it is good to have such a letter. People will read it, they will understand that they should not give it too much weight after reading it, and they will also see that you have nothing to hide, and nothing bad happened during your master.

You should really only not have a letter from your last qualification step if you expect it to be *negative*. Not having such a letter will raise questions and tend to count against you.